# Laravel : Injecting a controller in a view of another controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say I have a `NewsController::lastNews` who can fetch and display some News.

I want to display this news in many others controllers (`HomeController`, `WhateverController`).

**Option 1 : Fetching the data on each controller :** I can fetch the data in each wanted controller (HomeController, WhateverController) directly, via a Service, or even a Trait then pass it to the view, then @include the template of my news in the template of the controller, but this looks like *not very smooth*

**Option 2, my favorite so far : Using @inject in my templates :** This is very close to the `render(controller())` of Symfony but I want to know if there is any issues with this because it is not documented for using it with controllers.

```
@inject('news', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController')
<div> {{ $news->lastNews(3) }} </div>
```

What is the recommended way to share data + views in Laravel ?
Thanks.

Comment: Option 3: use a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `View Composer` for this purpose. You can create a file that would fetch data and then specify in which views that data is available.

You would need to create `ViewServiceProvider` and register it in the `config/app.php` `providers` section.

In the `ViewServiceProvider` you can specify in the `boot()` method what view would have a specific view composer

Example of ViewServiceProvider

```
class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('your.view.name', YourComposerName::class);
    }
}
```

Example of a view composer:

```
use Illuminate\View\View;

class YourComposerName
{
    /**
    * Bind data to the view.
    *
    * @param  View  $view
    * @return void
    */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {

        $view->with('variable_name', ['data_that_will_be_passed_to_the_view']]);
    }
}
```

Link to documentation - [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: Hi, sounds good. I can inject data on specified views with that. 
I've just tested with an @include('lastnews') and it is fine.

Comment: Hi @Neekobus, yes @include('lastnews') becomes a sort of independent component that has data and can be easily inserted in other views.

Comment: I can even pass the the quantity of news and reading it in the $view properties
`@include('lastnews', [qty=>3])`
and `$view->qty` in the compose method.

Comment: Just to clarify: you could create a view composer, compose the data to your `lastnews` component and then just include the component in other views without passing any data from the parent view.

Comment: Yes ! @include("lastnews") can work, but with @include("lastnew", [anyData=>anyValue])  we can even pass anyData to the compose method to work for.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are not meant to have static methods defined in them. Usually the best practice of defining controller methods is to have only model actions like `create`, `update` , `fetch` , `delete` etc as methods.

Your `blade` files should never have any `php` code included in them. In case you want to have shared functionality between different controllers Laravel has a global `helpers.php` file where you can define your static/non-static methods.
You can read more about it [here](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers)